# Checking if function was called with right arguments

Tags: python, coding-style, assert

Which coding-style is *better* / *correct* and *why*?
Using assert statement in each function:

```
def fun_bottom(arg):
    assert isinstance(arg, int)
    #blah blah

def fun_middle(arg):
    assert isinstance(arg, int)
    fun_bottom(arg)
    #blah blah

def fun_top(arg):
    assert isinstance(arg, int)
    fun_middle(arg)
    #blah blah
```

Or, because we know that type of arg is checked in fun_bottom function, just omit assertions in fun_middle and fun_top? Or maybe there's another solution?

**EDIT #1**
Ouch, I was misunderstood. I just used assert isinstance(arg, int) as an example. I'll rewrite the question:

Which one to use:

Option 1:
Check if argument fulfil function's requirements in each function:

```
def fun_bottom(arg):
    assert arg > 0
    #blah blah

def fun_middle(arg):
    assert arg > 0
    fun_bottom(arg)
    #blah blah

def fun_top(arg):
    assert arg > 0
    fun_middle(arg)
    #blah blah
```

Option 2: Because we know that argument is checked in bottom-most function, we make no assertions in middle- and top- functions:

```
def fun_bottom(arg):
    assert arg > 0
    #blah blah

def fun_middle(arg):
    fun_bottom(arg)
    #blah blah

def fun_top(arg):
    fun_middle(arg)
    #blah blah
```

Comment: Don't assert on type anywhere. Learn to love duck typing, and rely on the methods being defined that you expect to be defined.

Comment: Why do you think you need to assert this at all? If you want to write functions that only accept declared argument types, do so in a statically typed language like Java. Otherwise, write Python the way it is meant to be written.

Comment: You  need to use duck typing.  Normalize the input in a `try/except`, then do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: Oh, I thought using type assertion is good practice. Anyway, I gave isinstance(arg, int) just as an example. Let's swap it for, for example, assert arg > 0. How about now?

Comment: Type assertion is basically the opposite of duck typing. Assertions exist for specific debugging purposes, but they should never go in production code, and you should **certainly** never rely on them to do flow-control for you (since *they are turned off if `__debug__` is turned off*). If you need to do explicit value/type/whatever checking, *do it explicitly*. Otherwise, just put `try` and `except` around things that you expect might fail.

Comment: I have tried to answer but this seems like a really hard riddle, top calls middle middle calls bottom, bottom asserts something then then bottom runs middle runs and top runs? who calls top? some real code to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a more pythonic way of doing things would me more like:

```
def fun_fun(some_int): # function that takes hopefully an int/float
    try: # not sure if we got the correct value
        return_value = some_int + 4 % 4 # mathz
        return return_value # return mathz
    except TypeError: # if we didn't get an int/float we'd get this
        return None # So you can return None or do what you like
```

See: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

EDIT:

Maybe you want:

```
def fun_bottom(arg):
    if arg > 0:
        #blah blah
    else:
        #foo
```

Assert isn't supposed to be used in the manor your wanting it to be, have a read of:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively